# AAPanel - Installation fails for PHP 8.0.11 on ARM EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, php-8, amazon-linux-2

### Problem Statement

Trying to install PHP8.0 on ARM based server with OS Amazon-Linux-2 having aaPanel as the server management software installed.

Looking forward for solutions with perspective from aaPanel.

#### Environment Info

- Bit:64 Mem:952M Core:2 gcc:7.3.1 cmake:2.8.12.2
- Linux 4.14.248-189.473.amzn2.aarch64 aarch64
- ERROR: php-8.0.11 install failed.

#### Error

- checking for brotli/decode.h... no
- configure: error: BROTLI libs and/or directories were not found where specified!
- cat: /etc/redhat-release: No such file or directory

#### aaPanel Screenshot

[image]

Comment: And what's your question about this? Is this even related to programming?

Comment: It's about installation of PHP8.0 on ARM based served running Amazon-Linux-2 hosted with aaPanel